# Testing Sample Bot framework (C# SDK) using bot emulator

Tags: botframework

I want to test sample AlarmBot Application which is available in sample C#-SDK.
I have also downloaded Bot framework Emulator to test but I am not able to test it. please tell me how to resolve the problem?

The image shows the error:
[image: Emulator error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emulator URL you are using is wrong. You have to use `http://localhost:9000/` for that.

BTW, there is a new version of the emulator, as explained [here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/tools/bot-framework-emulator/).